# Workflow Runner with RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I'd like to run a workflow that a user can define and provide to a program which will be run with RxJS. Each item in the workflow would have an action, inputs, and outputs:

```
const steps = [
  { 
    action: someAction,
    inputs: [],
    outputs: []
  }
]
```

The outputs may not be defined; they might just be the result of the action. I'm not 100% sure yet. It could go either way. In addition, this object may not be everything. They may have to define the operator to use as well, something like that.

I know that I could take the above, and output each step in an RxJS pipeline like this:

```
from(steps).pipe(
  ... // operators here
).subscribe()
```

Technically, each step could run this way, but step 2 would need as its inputs the outputs from step 1:

Step 1 runs, produces outputs → Step 2 runs with inputs coming from step 1

My issue is running each step in the array where I can get the result and use that result in the next step of the pipeline. If I was hard coding the pipeline, I think I would be able to do it with a series of `switchMaps`, but not sure how I could declare the pipeline generically so that the user could provide the action to take and then getting the inputs and outputs.

Here's an example of what a workflow might be:

Step 1: query a database for a user's information
Step 2: take that information and send an email
Step 3: save result of email in database

```
const steps = [
  {
    action: fetch('path/to/api'),
    inputs: userId,
    outputs: ['name', 'email']
  },
  {
    action: sendEmail(name, email),
    inputs: [name, email],
    outputs: status
  },
  {
    action: saveToDatabase(status),
    inputs: status,
    outputs: result
  }
];
```

Again, the shape of the objects is not set in stone, but something like this will need to be done.

Any tips or ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since the output of step `N` is the input of step `N + 1`, it makes me think of something like `scan`. But since the action that produces an output is not synchronous, maybe the `mergeScan` operator can be used.

Assuming that a step has a slightly modified structure:

```js
const steps = [
  {
    action: userId => fetch(`path/to/api/${userId}`),
    inputs: [userId],
    outputs: ['name', 'email']
  },

  {
    action: (name, email) => sendEmail(name, email),
    inputs: ['name', 'email'],
    outputs: 'status'
  },
]
```

I think an approach would be:

```js
from(steps).pipe(
  mergeScan(
    // The `accumulator` function
    // It is assumed that both `prevOutput` and `step.inputs` are of type **array**
    (prevOutput, step, index) => step.action(...prevOutput === null ? step.inputs : prevOutput),
    
    // The seed(initial value),
    null,

    // The `concurrent` argument - the same with the one used on `mergeMap`
    1
  ),
);
```

Notice there are a few changes, in order to cover all cases:

- the `step.inputs` property is now an **array**
- as a result from the above, the `step.outputs` property is now an **array**
- the `step.action` is now a function that takes in the supposed inputs
- only the first step will have **real values** for the inputs, instead of just strings, because the inputs of the next step depend on the outputs of the previous, and the first step does not have a previous step

I'd also say that with this approach, the `outputs` property is useful only for debugging purposes, since all you can have there are string values, because you can't know the actual values beforehand.

Comment: Thanks! This almost seems to work perfectly. I just need to figure out why the conditional for previous output or step inputs as the arguments to the action is causing an error. It keeps saying that the action expects one parameter, but I'm providing 0 or more. I'm guessing it's a typescript thing and I can figure it out but that's the only issue I think I'm running into so far.

Comment: @pjlamb12 I think it’s kind of challenging to cover all cases in one place, maybe it will work if you make the action type something like ‘(...args: any[]) => any’?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try typing it very generically. In the short term, making the action parameter optional got rid of the error. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @pjlamb12 I’m glad I could help!